# What is more suitable in performance aspect - Multithreading or Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I would like to run several receivers that will receive data in different ports, but are basically the same.
What is more suitable in performance aspect - Multithreading or Multiprocessing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the application is I/O-bound, threading will suffice (and be faster).

If it's CPU-bound, and you're using cpython or another Python interpreter with a [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), multiprocessing is the right choice instead.

Answer (score 5):

The trouble with Python is that the most common interpreters contain a global lock -- commonly known as the GIL.  This means that only one thread can execute python code at once, so a multi-process model can often make more efficient use of multiple cores than a multi-thread model.

Comment: `s/python/cpython` (and PyPy)

Comment: @phihag: Good point.  The GIL is a feature of the interpreter, not the language.  I think most people will still conflate the two, though.

Comment: If cpython has GIL and only one thread can execute python code at once, what's the point in using it at all??

Comment: @iTayb Well, it's the "official" Python from http://python.org , and probably the most-deployed one. cpython is nearly always the first implementation of new Python features. For example, neither of PyPy, jython, and IronPython implements anything more than Python 2.7!

Comment: @phihag I think my question wasn't clear enough... I'm asking why someone would ever use multithreading in cpython when he can use multiprocessing and get better performance.

Comment: @iTayb multiprocessing only performs better if your application is CPU bound. Inter-thread communication (and switching between threads) is *way* faster than inter-process communication. Also, the startup is way slower with multiprocessing since you need to fork instead of creating a thread.

Comment: @iTayb: Also, if your process is CPU-bound and you've either re-written the most performance-critical sections is C or you're using libraries which are written in C, those bits of code can often run in parallel.